# Select and count in the same query on two tables

Tags: sql

I've got these two tables:

`___Subscriptions`

```
|--------|--------------------|--------------|
| SUB_Id | SUB_HotelId        | SUB_PlanName |
|--------|--------------------|--------------|
| 1      | cus_AjGG401e9a840D | Free         |
|--------|--------------------|--------------|
```

`___Rooms`

```
|--------|-------------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_HotelId       |
|--------|-------------------|
| 1      |cus_AjGG401e9a840D |
| 2      |cus_AjGG401e9a840D |
| 3      |cus_AjGG401e9a840D |
| 4      |cus_AjGG401e9a840D |
|--------|-------------------|
```

I'd like to select the `SUB_PlanName` and count the rooms with the same HotelId.

So I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'ROO_Count', SUB_PlanName
FROM ___Rooms
JOIN ___Subscriptions
ON ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId = ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId
WHERE ROO_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
```

and

```
SELECT 
    SUB_PlanName, 
    (
        SELECT Count(ROO_Id) 
        FROM ___Rooms
        Where ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId
    ) as ROO_Count 
FROM  ___Subscriptions
WHERE SUB_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
```

But I get empty datas.

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a query that joins the tables and produces a result?  Maybe we can work from that.  ALSO:  What database manager (software) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` whenever you do some aggregation(here COUNT()). Below query will give you the number of `ROO_ID` only for the `SUB_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'` because you have this condition in `WHERE`. If you want the COUNTs for all Hotel_IDs then you can simply remove the `WHERE` filter from this query.

```
SELECT s.SUB_PlanName, COUNT(*) as 'ROO_Count' 
FROM ___Rooms r
JOIN ___Subscriptions s
ON s.SUB_HotelId = r.ROO_HotelId
WHERE r.ROO_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
GROUP BY s.SUB_PlanName;
```

To be safe, you can also use `COUNT(DISTINCT r.ROO_Id)` if you don't want to double count a repeating `ROO_Id`. But your table structures seem to have unique(non-repeating) `ROO_Id`s so using a `COUNT(*)` should work as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but with this query it make the same. I check twice and my tables don't contains errors.

Comment: Can you try running without `WHERE` clause to see if the join is working for other HotelIds?

Comment: I have this error: `#1054 - Field '___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId' unknown in the ON clause.`

Comment: Using original table names should have worked. I just replaced them by aliases r and s `ON s.SUB_HotelId = r.ROO_HotelId`

Comment: By removing the alias `s` and `r` I see the column names but no datas in it.

Comment: A possible reason could be leadint/trailing spaces in your `HotelID` field. Can you try `WHERE TRIM(r.ROO_HotelId) = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'` in the above query? If TRIM throws an error, depending on your SQL platform there should be a similar function.

Comment: Also try running `select * from ___Subscriptions where TRIM(SUB_HotelId) = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'` to check if you are getting no data in the result here too.